# I am trying to detect eyes using Tensorflow. Is there any pre-trained model of eye detection?

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, deep-learning, detection, eye-detection

I have done eyes detection in OpenCV using eye.xml Haarcascade classifiers but have no idea how to do it using Tensorflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to detect eyes in what I assume would be photos, you can always use [Mask R-CNN](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN). Since you just want to detect eyes, you can use something called the [COCO dataset](http://cocodataset.org/#home). The Common Objects In Context is a collection of thousands of different objects, including eyes and faces, that can help detect the features you want in a photo.

Comment: Thank you for repling.Sorry I didn't mention it that I want to detect eyes in a Video. Then also I can use COCO datasheet?

Comment: Yes, you just have to use the data set on the video instead of an image.